How to use an accesskey to activate a group of radio buttons?
This question is similar to Using the HTML 'label' tag with radio buttons:
I have two fieldsets, selectable by an accesskey, each being a table (but simplified here).
When I select the second fieldset, the first input element (radio group) is selected, and I can use the cursor keys to make a choice.
When I hit the access key for the second row (checkbox) I can toggle the checkbox.
But when I hit the accesskey for the radio group (to go back to the radio group), the radio buttons don't have the focus!


label {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder
}

.sf-legend {
  font-size: medium;
  font-family: sans-serif
}

.sf-lab {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder
}

.sf-help {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
  color: #3333bb
}

div.vsp {
  height: 1em
}
<div class="vsp" name="vsp-big"></div>
<form method="post" action="/directory/94676003/query/2" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="sf">
  <fieldset class="sf-fset">
    <legend class="sf-legend" accesskey="s" data-i="0">Suchkriterien</legend>
    <p class="sf-help">Alle angegebenen Suchkriterien müssen für einen Treffer erfüllt sein.</p>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="vsp"></div>
  <fieldset class="sf-fset">
    <legend accesskey="u" data-i="1" class="sf-legend">Suchmodus</legend>
    <p class="sf-help">Modus: Was soll ausgegeben werden?</p>
    <table summary="Suchmodus" class="sf">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label data-i="1" accesskey="o" class="sf-lab" for="srch-mode">Modus</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label><input type="radio" name="srch-mode" value="telephoneNumber" checked="checked"  data-i="0" accesskey="t" id="srch-mode-telephoneNumber" title="telephoneNumber"/>Telefon</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="srch-mode" value="pager"  accesskey="f" data-i="0" id="srch-mode-pager" title="pager"/>Funk</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="srch-mode" value="facsimileTelephoneNumber"  accesskey="x" data-i="2" id="srch-mode-facsimileTelephoneNumber" title="facsimileTelephoneNumber"/>FAX-Nummer</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="srch-mode" value="mail"  title="mail" data-i="5" accesskey="l" id="srch-mode-mail"/>E-Mail Adresse</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="srch-mode" value="uid"  title="uid" data-i="5" accesskey="z" id="srch-mode-uid"/>Benutzerkennung</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="srch-mode" value="mobile"  data-i="17" accesskey="r" id="srch-mode-mobile" title="mobile"/>Mobiltelefonnummer</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="srch-mode" value="homePhone"  title="homePhone" data-i="0" id="srch-mode-homePhone" accesskey="p"/>Private Telefonnummer</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="srch-need" accesskey="i" data-i="1" class="sf-lab">Einschränkungen</label></td>
          <td>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="srch-need" value="not-null" checked="checked"  id="srch-need" data-i="7" accesskey="g"/>Einträge ohne Angaben unterdrücken</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="vsp" name="vsp-big"></div>
  <label for="submit" accesskey="c" data-i="2" class="sf-lab"><input type="submit" name=".submit" value="Suchen" id="submit" /></label>



As the code is trimmed-down (accesskeys not highlighted) and out of context, here are some instructions:
s selects the first fieldset, u the second.
In the example the first fieldset is practically empty, but it has several fields and buttons in reality.
In the second fieldset o selects the first row, while i selects the second row.
The access keys to select individual radio buttons are: t, f, x, l, z, r, p
In the original rendering the lower part looks like this (you can see the access keys):

Note in this special case I could select the second fieldset to activate the first input element (that happens to be the radio group), but I'd like to be able to activate the radio group as itself (using the o key for "Modus").
So what I want is:
Accesskey i ("Einschränkungen") toggles the checkbox (because that gets the focus).
I want accesskey o ("Modus") to set the focus to the radio group (so that I could move the cursor keys to make a selection inside the group).

You are incorrectly using label elements - they can be associated either using a for="ID of input" type syntax or by wholly encompassing the element they are describing. In the above you have the for=NAME. Also you have shared none of your Javascript nor really identified a clear question

@ProfessorAbronsius A reference would be nice. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label says: "The  HTML element represents a caption for an item in a user interface.", so I don't see a restriction there. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element says: "The label element represents a caption in a user interface. The caption can be associated with a specific form control, known as the label element's labeled control, either using the for attribute, or by putting the form control inside the label element itself."

I know of the reference on Mozilla - the fact still remains that these labels are incorrectly associated with the input element that you are intending so in terms of accessibility they fail.

Why shouldn't a radio group have a label?

I'm not suggesting that for a moment. In the above, for instance, you have label elements with no for attribute but wholly encompassing the input element ( perfectly fine ) but there is a label using a for attribute which references the name of the following input elements which is not, afaik, how these are to be associated. This was merely intended as a comment as it likely has no bearing on what you are trying to do with accesskeys
